# Javascript Efficiency Question: multiple getElementById() vs getElementsByTagName() and looping through result

Tags: javascript, dom, performance

I was wondering if it would be more efficient to use document.getElementById() n number of times or to use document.getElementsByTagName() and loop through the result looking for the specific Element ids?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all depends.  How many elements with given IDs do you have?  How many elements with the same tag name?

For example if you want elements with IDs 1 and 3 and you have:

```
<ul>
  <li id="1">1</li>
  <li id="2">2</li>
  <li id="3">3</li>
  <!-- Followed by 10,000 more li tags -->
</ul>
```

you would be better off calling `getElementById()` twice.  But if you want everything except ID 15, you would probably be better off doing the list and checking IDs.

Another alternative is to add a class to the specific elements that you want to select.  Then you can select by class (perhaps with the [JQuery class selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/class)) which will give you good performance all round.

Keep in mind that Javascript performance vary wildly [between browsers](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1001_3-10030888-92.html) and even between [versions of browsers](http://www.mozilla-europe.org/en/firefox/).  Best to do some testing against your target browsers.

Comment: Thanks For the reply Leonm. There are 5 specific id's, but no way to tell how many elements could be on the page. I'm going to test this out, thanks again.

Comment: In case of 5 elements it doesn't matter. In general, since getElementById is used very often, browsers optimize it the most.